# ios App crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) on ipad ios 7.1.1 device

Tags: ios, crash, exc-bad-access, segmentation-fault

I have no idea about this crash. The crash happens at various screens without any actions sometimes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b3a1626 objc_msgSend + 6
1   UIKit                           0x33301b46 +[UIViewController _viewControllerForFullScreenPresentationFromView:] + 174
2   UIKit                           0x33301614 -[UIWindow _scrollToTopViewsUnderScreenPointIfNecessary:resultHandler:] + 428
3   UIKit                           0x3330143e -[_UIScrollsToTopInitiatorView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 210
4   UIKit                           0x3330134e -[UIStatusBar touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 334
5   UIKit                           0x33255790 forwardTouchMethod + 228
6   UIKit                           0x3310371c -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
7   UIKit                           0x330fe6e6 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 754
8   UIKit                           0x330d38e8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
9   UIKit                           0x330d1f92 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7098
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3087e258 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3087d726 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3087bf1a __CFRunLoopRun + 618
13  CoreFoundation                  0x307e6f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
14  CoreFoundation                  0x307e6cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  GraphicsServices                0x356e065e GSEventRunModal + 134
16  UIKit                           0x33132168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
17  MyApp                           0x0029c0a0 main (main.m:16)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b8a4ab4 start + 0
```

Comment: You have a memory management problem somewhere. Finding it can be difficult. Can you reproduce the error while debugging the app through Xcode?

Comment: No am unable to reproduce the error in a regular manner. I tried to reproduce by placing an exception breakpoint and after an hour of effort encountered with the issue. But the exception was shown at UIApplicationMain. Also there were no memory leaks i observed in instruments. But the concern is when my app uses the WebView at some places, the memory goes beyond 100MB sometimes.

Comment: It's not a memory leak problem. Somewhere you seem to be trying to access a deallocated object.

Comment: @HarishGopinath, were you able to find a solution?